# jQuery TextGrad plugin (text gradient)

Tags: jquery, text, gradient

Not sure what I'm missing here... I think i've got all the right pieces in the right place.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3qGq/

I'm trying to use this plugin here: https://github.com/subtenante/TextGrad

Seems like it should work, but no dice.

Any help / ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle the plugin js is not getting downloaded. Here is the working fiddle where I have just copied the plugin js into script section as it to make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/d3qGq/1/